# from C++ how do I type a string to my desktop or word document on my computer (not window)

Tags: c++

So far from c++ I found how to move the mouse to position x and y and to right and left click.  I cannot seem to figure out how to click on something and then type from c++ .  If I had a word document up I want to be able to click it, open it and type something into it. Thanks in advance !

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
SetCursorPos(97,758);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0); // Left click
Sleep( 1000 );
SetCursorPos(418,657);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0); 
SetCursorPos(266,34);
Sleep( 1000 );
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0); 
//right here is where I would like to type something to the document
}
```

Comment: Please make your question more exact and describe more. I myself can't understand anything from your question. Make your questions eye-appealing to the visitors. Thx

Comment: Well you have everything to open the onscreen keyboard and click on the buttons!

Comment: `keybd_event` (deprecated) or `SendInput` will be of great help.

Comment: Just for completeness: Please note that this is not something you want to do for a production environment because relying on screen positions is very fragile. A better way to do this would be to use an interop API.

Comment: Look into the accessibility API.

Comment: @confusopoly sure you wouldn't want to mistype the word "duck" for example. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using SendInput

[SendInput on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
    INPUT ip;

    // Set up a generic keyboard event.
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.wScan = 0; // hardware scan code for key
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    // Press the "A" key
    ip.ki.wVk = 0x41; // virtual-key code for the "a" key
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    // Release the "A" key
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
```

Comment: But here is the killer question! How do you change the keyboard layout programmatically? Ah I guess I already found the answer :(

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix what do you mean change the keyboard layout programmatically? this is a desktop not a smartphone..do you mean change lanauge?

Comment: Well yes, the language is often called a keyboard layout because for one language there may have multiple dispositions (layouts).

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix  LoadKeyboardLayout - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646305%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Wow you guys reply quick! Thanks everyone, I tried Dory's and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @RyanTackett glad to help Ryan..so happens I did too much Win32API :) If you like the answer, would be cool if you accept it as the answer for this question :)